# How can I change the order in which Google Sitelinks are displayed?

Tags: seo, google-search, sitelinks

See the image for reference. In this scenario I'm the owner of the domain, and I want "Learn Business and Creative Skills" to be on top instead of the "Shop Courses" page. How can I make that happen?

[image: Adjust google sitelinks positions in search results]

Comment: Google does not offer any tool to directly change the order these links are displayed in. And typically, you can't remove a particular sitelink without removing the page from search results entirely (Google used to offer a "demote sitelink" tool but no longer does). Perhaps there is some trick that I am not aware of, though.